# 'int' object is not suscriptable

Tags: python

So everytime I try to use my `Point.top()` command I keep getting:

```
 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

And this the code:

```
def top():
    datalist = sorted(Point.dPoint.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True)
    t = 1
    top = []
    for l in datalist:
        top.append(l[0].title()+": "+str(l[1][0])+(" point" if l[1][0] > 1 else " points"))
        if t == 15:
             break
        t+=1
    return top
```

This is inside the file and how it saves:

```
charles 45
tim 32
bob 67
```

I'm not sure why that error keeps happening. The code is suppose to get the top 15 people of who has the highest points. It would return this:

```
["Bob: 67 points", "Charles: 45 points", "Tim: 32 points"]
```

Comment: but do you know what the error *means*? From there, it's simple deduction...

Comment: Not really. I only know it's a int object error.

Comment: `int` was the object, and you tried to do `[index]` on it.

Comment: [. . .]? Could you explain?

Comment: access an element in the container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to make code more explicit, e.g.:

```
def top():
    player_points_couples = sorted(Point.dPoint.items(), key=lambda player_point_couple: player_point_couple[1][0], reverse=True)
    top_players_number = 1
    top_players = []
    for player, points in player_points_couples :
        top_players.append(player.title()+": "+str(points[0])+(" point" if points[0] > 1 else " points"))
        if top_players_number == 15:
             break
        top_players_number += 1
    return top_players
```

In this way you'll find the strange expressions:

```
player_point_couple[1][0]
...
points[0]
```

which mean "the first element of 'points'"... but 'points' is a number, no elements inside!

*EDIT*
Just to go into pythonic style:

```
def top():
    from operator import itemgetter
    player_points_couples = sorted(Point.dPoint.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    string_template_singular = "%s: %d point"
    string_template_plural = "%s: %d points"
    top_players = []
    for player, points in player_points_couples[:15]:
        string_template = string_template_plural if points > 1 else string_template_singular
        top_players.append(string_template % (player.title(), points))

    return top_players
```

Comment: Nice. That actually looks a lot cleaner than what I got xD

Comment: I don't seem to have operator.py. Do you know where I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

One of your variables is an `int`, and you're doing `variable[0]`, which you can't do with an `int`.

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Aug 25 2013, 14:58:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.1 ((branches/release_31 156863))] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a = 42
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. The error could also be in the `x` variable, you didn't post a full error with line numbers (you didn't even copy/paste the precise error, since it contains a typo).

Comment: `l[0]` couldn't cause this. check `l[1]` or `x[1]`

Comment: So what if I did str(x[1][0])? I think that could fix it.

Comment: Perhaps? I have no idea what your data looks like, or what `Point.top` is; Start by having a clear picture of how your data looks like (You can use `print` to view what it looks like), and then reason about it.

Comment: no, that won't fix it. Looks like you still don't get it. debug 101: `print`.